# How to get RSpec to call a singular route when testing controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

Anyone know how to get RSpec to call a singular route when testing controller?

It can't find the route b/c it doesn't know to look for a singular controller so I need a way to specify it.

routes.rb

```
resource :settings_group, :path => "/settings/scheduling/"
```

settings_groups_controller_spec.rb

```
describe SettingsGroupsController do

  describe "GET show" do

    let(:describe_action) { get :show }

    it "sets @settings_group" do
      describe_action
      assigns(:settings_group).should be_kind_of(SettingsGroup)
    end

  end
end
```

...

```
 ActionController::RoutingError:
   No route matches {:controller=>"settings_groups"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity, but why does settings_group_controller.rb have

describe SettingsGroupsController (with an s)

Shouldn't they match?

Comment: Oh, that was a typo, sorry. The file is properly named 'settings_groups_controller_spec.rb'

Comment: I was wondering something similar...the route refers to 'settings_group' and the model is SettingsGroup. I would expect the controller to be settings_groups which suggests that the route is incorrect. I offer this as a comment because there's not enough information there for me to make a clear decision.

Comment: ah, ok. I'd suggest that your route is wrong then. it should be: resource :settings_groups, :path => "/settings/scheduling/" -- the s at the end of settings_group...

Comment: Thanks, guys. Turns out the routes were correct, but when I changed the route to be singular I forgot to change the redirects in the controller to point to 'show' instead of 'index'. Singular routes don't use 'index', they instead use 'show' as the default action.